# What mistake am I making with my web.config file?

Tags: .net, web-config

So I need to remove the .html from the ends of my urls on my website
This is my first time working with a web.config I think I probably made a stupid error, so here's everything I've done so far.

- I created a file called web.config

-I pasted this in:

```
<configuration>   
  <system.webServer>   
    <rewrite>   `       
        <rules>             
            <rule name="RewriteHTML">
              <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">                     
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />                     
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />                 
                </conditions>                 
             <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />             
            </rule>                
        </rules>      
    </rewrite>   
 </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

- Then I added it to the root of my site (the folder above httpdocs). Nothing Happened. I also tried adding it into httpdocs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this blog post : https://www.saotn.org/iis-url-rewrite-hide-php-extension/ - you did everything correctly. But actually config you made - not remove extension itself. It`s only allow you to navigate URLs without typing ".html" at the end. Try to use the second approach described in that blog post - to be able to remove ".html" extension in requests.

Comment: I had no idea that it was partially working! Instead of changing my webconfig file I now just changed the links in navbar, and this in conjunction with what I did above worked